# Maximum run in binary digit expansions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, binary

For numbers between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^{k}-1$, how many have a maximum run of $n$ identical digits in base $2$? For instance, $1000110101111001$ in base $2$ has a maximum run of 4.

See picture below showing the number of numbers with a maximum run equal to $2$, between $1$ and $2^{k}-1$, for various values of $k$. Clearly, it is a simple function of Fibonacci numbers. This seems to generalize to maximum run equal to $3, 4, 5$ and so on. See this [previous question on the subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439557/maximum-run-of-zeros-in-a-n-bit-binary-string). However, the people who answered that question provide no reference and no explanation. It is also said (in that same question) that in a random string of $0/1$ of length $k$, one expects the longest sequence of zeros to be roughly of length $\log k$. I am also very interested in that statement (if you replace "longest sequence of zero" by "longest sequence whether zero or one"), but where can I find a proof?

[image]

The goal is to construct a sub-sequence of integers that has a max run less than (say) $\sqrt{k}$ for all $k$ so that as $k$ increases, and you divide the numbers in the sub-sequence by a power of two so that each number becomes a fraction between $0.5$ and $1$, you end up at the limit with an irrational number that has a specific proportion of zero and one in its binary expansion. The final goal is to find a mathematical constant that we know for sure, based on the aforementioned construction, to be either normal or not normal.

Comment: I've no way to help toward an answer, but +1 for including the source of the question.

Comment: An interesting link in the previous question referenced in my post, is broken. I was able to find the correct URL: https://www.csun.edu/~hcmth031/tlroh.pdf (title: The longest run of heads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the same as asking about max number of runs (of consecutive 1's)
in a binary string of length $n=k-1$.

In [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496/number-of-occurrences-of-k-consecutive-1s-in-a-binary-string-of-length-n-conta/2045737#2045737) it is explained that the
*Number of  binary strings,  with $s$ "$1$"'s and $m$ "$0$"'s in total, that have up to $r$ consecutive $1$s*
is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m + 1)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m + 1} \right)} {
\left( { - 1} \right)^k  \binom{m+1}{k}
  \binom {s + m - k\left( {r + 1} \right) }{s - k\left( {r + 1} \right) }
} 
$$

So, the *cumulative* number we are looking for is:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & C(n,r) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,m\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {
N_b (n - m,r,m + 1)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,m\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over {r + 1}}\, \le \,m + 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m+1}{k}
 \binom{
  n - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}
  {n - m - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } } }  \cr} 
 } \tag{1}$$

Of course it is $C(n,n)=2^n$.
It is also [OEIS seq. A126198](http://oeis.org/A126198).

[image: Consec_1_1]

By splitting the first binomial in $m+1$ and applying
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{z^{\,m} } \over {m!}}\left( {{d \over {dz}}} \right)^{\,m} \left( {1 + z} \right)^{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{k\, \ge \,0} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\,\;z^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{n^{\underline {\,m\,} } z^{\,m} } \over {m!}}\left( {1 + z} \right)^{\,n - m}  = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)z^{\,m} \left( {1 + z} \right)^{\,n - m}  \cr} 
$$
we can express $C(n,r)$ also as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & C(n,r) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m\, \le \,n} {N_m (n,r,m)} \quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers  }m,n,r} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{n \over {r + 2}} \le \,{n \over {r + 1}}} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  n - k\left( {r + 2} \right) \cr}  \right)2^{\,n - k\left( {r + 2} \right)} }  + 2\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( {{{n + 1} \over {r + 2}} \le \,{n \over {r + 1}}} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k
  \left( \matrix{ n - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  n + 1 - k\left( {r + 2} \right) \cr}  \right)2^{\,n - k\left( {r + 2} \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{{n + 1} \over {r + 2}} \le \,{n \over {r + 1}}} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( {\left( \matrix{
  n + 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  n + 1 - k\left( {r + 2} \right) \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  n - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  n + 1 - k\left( {r + 2} \right) \cr}  \right)} \right)2^{\,n - k\left( {r + 2} \right)} }  \cr} 
 } \tag{2}$$

Using the o.g.f. for $Nb$ provided in the post above, it is possible to provide
quite a neat o.g.f. for $C(n,r)$ as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F(z,r) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {C(n,r)z^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,m\,\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {z^{\,m} N_b (n - m,r,m + 1)z^{\,n - m} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,m} {z^{\,m} \left( {{{1 - z^{\,r + 1} } \over {1 - z}}} \right)^{m + 1} }  = \left( {{{1 - z^{\,r + 1} } \over {1 - z}}} \right){1 \over {1 - z{{1 - z^{\,r + 1} } \over {1 - z}}}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{1 - z^{\,r + 1} } \over {1 - 2z + z^{\,r + 2} }} \cr} 
 } \tag{3}$$

From the above it comes that $C(n,r)$ is just a shifted version of the [Higher -order Fibonacci Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order), i.e.
$$
C(n,r) = F_{\,n + r + 1}^{\,\left( {r + 1} \right)} 
$$
with the definition given therein.

In this interesting paper ["A Simpliﬁed Binet Formula for k-Generalized Fibonacci Numbers" - G.P.B. Dresden, Z. Du](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0304)
we learn that also the $(r+1)$-nacci numbers can be expressed by formulas similar to that of Binet, which leads to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & C(n,r) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^r {{{\alpha _{\,k}  - 1} \over {2 + \left( {r + 2} \right)\left( {\alpha _{\,k}  - 2} \right)}}\alpha _{\,k} ^{\,n + 1} }
  \quad \left| \matrix{ \;1 \le r \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le n \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \alpha _{\,0} , \cdots ,\alpha _{\,r} \;{\rm roots}\,{\rm of}\,x^{\,r + 1}  - \left( {1 + x +  \cdots  + x^{\,r} } \right) \cr} 
 } \tag{4}$$

In that paper it is also shown that the polynomial $x^{\,r + 1}  - \left( {1 + x +  \cdots  + x^{\,r} } \right)$ has only one root (call it $\alpha$) outside
of the unit circle, and which is real and
$$
2 - {1 \over {r + 1}} < \alpha  < 2
$$
Therefore, asymptotically for large $n$ , we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
C(n,r) \approx {{\alpha  - 1} \over {2 + \left( {r + 2} \right)\left( {\alpha  - 2} \right)}}\alpha ^{\,n + 1} \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;1 \le r \hfill \cr 
  \;n \to \infty  \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The asymptotic formula looks more complicated than I would have expected, but I am sure more accurate than what I had in mind.

Comment: @VincentGranville as you know, asymptotic expressions can be  somewhat simplified depending on the degree of accuracy required. I intend to proceed and dig a bit more on that: will let you know.

Comment: @VincentGranville: Up to now, I just could find another expression for $C(n,r)$ which I added to my answer. I am looking for a better asymptotics.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thanks G Cab.

Comment: @VincentGranville: taken a further step, but the asymptotics remains elusive..

Comment: @VincentGranville: finally I came across an interesting paper dealing with Binet-like formulas for $(r+1)$-nacci numbers, from which the asymptotics for large $n$ follows easily.

Comment: @G Cab: Can you provide the reference? Thank you.

Comment: @VincentGranville: I put the referene in the answer, isn't ok ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze a simpler case first, $f_n(k)$: the number of binary strings of length $k$ that do not contain $1^n$.

Obviously $f_1(k) = 1$ for all $k$, as only the all-zero  or empty string does not contain $1$.

But $f_2(k)$ is more interesting. We have $f_2(0) = 1$ and $f_2(1) = 2$ by simple counting. But then we can make a simple argument:

> $f_2(k) = f_2(k-1) + f_2(k-2)$ because the number of binary strings of length $k$ that avoid $11$ is equal to the amount that avoid $11$ of length $k-1$ with string $0$ prepended plus the amount of length $k-2$ with string $10$ prepended.

You can generalize this argument for a recurrence for $f_n(k)$:

> $f_n(k) = f_n(k-1) + f_n(k-2) + \cdots + f_n(k-n)$ because the number of binary strings of length $k$ that avoid string $1^n$ is equal to the amount that avoid $1^n$ of length $k-1$ with string $0$ prepended plus the amount of length $k-2$ with binary digits $10$ prepended to the integer, and so forth, continuing until the amount of strings of length $k - n$ with binary string $1^{n-1}0$ prepended.

To get the starting numbers before the recurrence, we have:

$$\forall k< n:f_n(k) = 2^{k}$$

Now that we  have analyzed $f$ we can go back to your problem. First let $g_n(k)$ be the number of binary strings that a maximum sequence of ones exactly equal to  $n$. Verify for yourself that:

$$g_n(k) = f_{n+1}(k) - f_n(k)$$

Finally, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the binary strings of length $k$ and and the integers in $[1, 2^k)$  for our problem of counting the maximal sequence of ones.

Unfortunately I don't know where you got the numbers in your post from, as they are not correct. The above formula for $g_2$ yields [A000100](https://oeis.org/A000100) which is correct.

Comment: I think after editing my explanation, my numbers should be correct. It's the cumulative number for any string with length less or equal to $k$ rather than for length exactly equal to $k$. Anyway for max run equal to 3, I get the same sequence as  A000100, and this really answers my question: as it provides the appropriate references. Thank you!

Comment: After reading some references, I realized that his is equivalent to another problem: the number of compositions of $k$ in which the maximal part is specified (2 or 3 in the examples discussed here.)